# Add a active class to the clicked menu after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

```js
function zeetapro_help_details(app_function_id){
        var adminrootpath = $('#adminrootpath').val();
        var appname = $('#appsName').val();

        $.ajax({
        url:adminrootpath + appname + "/self_load_menu_help",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"HTML",
        data:{app_function_id:app_function_id},
        success:function(data)
        { 
             $('#help-container').html(data);

        }
    });

}
```

```html
<ul id="tree3" class="box-head nav nav-tabs nav-custom menu_help tree" data-toggle="tabs">
<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(36);"></li>
<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(51);"></li>
<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(256);"></li>
<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(166);"></li>
</ul>
```

How to add a class active to the clicked li menu after each ajax success,the sucess in loading some content on calling the function onclick event

Comment: Add $('.yourClass').addClass('newClass'); after $('#help-container').html(data);

Comment: This does a active class to all li items

Comment: Instead of your class add  this. Remove . ' etc.

Comment: Try this $(this).addClass('newClass')

Comment: Not working adding active class to all elements

Comment: adding active class to all elements at a time or on clicking each element?

Comment: on cliking one element the active class is added to all li items

Answer (score 2):

Add "**this**" within your function parameters

**Example -**

```
<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(this, 36);"></li>
```

And then change your function in js

```
function zeetapro_help_details(obj, app_function_id){

        var adminrootpath = $('#adminrootpath').val();
        var appname = $('#appsName').val();

        $.ajax({
        url:adminrootpath + appname + "/self_load_menu_help",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"HTML",
        data:{app_function_id:app_function_id},
        success:function(data)
        { 
             $(obj).addClass("active");
             $('#help-container').html(data);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: did you deleted all li's you have and add the one shubham added?

Comment: @CharantejGolla yes the li is coming in a loop.so I only one li with the code shubham given

Comment: TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.

Comment: function zeetapro_help_details(obj,app_function_id){
        var adminrootpath = $('#adminrootpath').val();
        var appname = $('#appsName').val();
       
        $.ajax({
        url:adminrootpath + appname + "/self_load_menu_help",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"HTML",
        data:{obj:obj,app_function_id:app_function_id},
        success:function(data)
        {    
             $(obj).addClass("active");
             $('#help-container').html(data);
             
        }
    });

}

Comment: `code`<ul id="tree3" class="box-head nav nav-tabs nav-custom menu_help tree" data-toggle="tabs">

<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(this,36);"></li>

<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(this,51);"></li>
<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(this,256);"></li>

<li class="" onclick="zeetapro_help_details(this,166);"></li>
</ul>

Comment: remove this obj:obj,